# Error with imagefilter() from GD (no file?)

Tags: php, gd, syntax-error, gdlib, imagefilter

I keep getting the following errors:

> /private/var/tmp/phpl3E3lq 
>   Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(/private/var/tmp/phpl3E3lq) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /sites/uploadresults.php on line 10
>   Conversion failed
>   Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /sites/uploadresults.php on line 22

```
<?php
move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'], "/sites/".$_FILES['Image']['name']) or die ('Could not upload');

echo $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name']

 ?>


<?php
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'])
?>

<?php
if($img && imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_PIXELATE, 3))
{
echo $img;
}
else
{

echo 'Conversion failed';
imagedestroy($img);

}

?>

<img src="http://localhost/<?php echo $_FILES['Image']['name'] ?>" />
```

I'm not sure what is going on. It seems like the $img isn't picking up the jpeg I'm trying to convert to a pixelated form. I'm new to this so it might be my syntax or something.

Comment: Sorry for the noob formatting. Still getting use to this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the new filename, not the original one from before you moved it:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("/sites/".$_FILES['Image']['name']);
```

Comment: I changed it to: http://pastebin.com/1Z4VMUCz

Still giving me:

/sites//private/var/tmp/phppKh29h 
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(/sites//private/var/tmp/phppKh29h) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /sites/uploadresults.php on line 16
Conversion failed
Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /sites/uploadresults.php on line 28



thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You've moved the file away from the `['tmp_name']` location, BEFORE you do the image create call. So when you call imagecreate() with that tmp name again, the file's no longer there.

Either do your image processing before you move the file, or use the "final destination" name of the file as your imagecreate argument.

As well: Note that the `['name']` parameter of the file upload is user-provided data, and CAN contain path information. You're blindly using it as as the destination filename in the move call, which means the user can dump their file anywhere on your server where the webserver has write permissions. Consider the case where they maliciously name their file `../../../../../etc/passwd`.